# NDK Not found unity 2021.6.f1

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-ndk, android-unity-plugin

I'm trying to build an android apk file from unity. I already installed all android tools as the Unity Hub shows :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaO0F.png

but when I try to get a build this happens :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnGd8.png

What I have tried is downloading NDK from this site :

https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r24-windows.zip

and facing this boy :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hkxas.png

Comment: Check the paths on the project

Comment: I did that path doesn't exist

Comment: So find the right one?

Comment: It looks like there is no other NDK installed but Hub is showing something different I even cant install new one ! @BugFinder

Comment: Well the zip downloads for me. So sounds like you need have a probes your end

Comment: Oh ok I tried using a proxy and it downloaded but Its not the needed version it needs r21 file do you have its link ?

Comment: Sorry. First - unless you fancy probably a long flight, doing a painfully dull task and going back. My #1 activity is loom prepping this weekend.   Second. Im not google. I have no idea for the link but im sure it will. I have enough in my head wothout memorising URLs of downloads.  Sorry